# facing error with getting the inctanse of documents fro FirbaseStore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]> i am using FLutterCore in my main method

i want to get my document from my firestore database and i am sure that my collection name is right
and if there any

```
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () async {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('chats/i2CTgCsK172ADGN8MFfA/messages')
          .snapshots()
          .listen(
        (data) {
          data.docs.forEach((docs) {
            print(docs.data()[0]['text']);
          });
        },
      );
      // await for (var maseg in FirebaseFirestore.instance
      //     .collection('chats/i2CTgCsK172ADGN8MFfA/messages')
      //     .snapshots()) {
      //   for (var data in maseg.docs) {
      //     print(data.);
      //   }
      // }
    },
  ),
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: sorry my fault.  i put the error now

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps do the following in your onPressed method, just to see whether the connection is working and you can get documents.

So now I added the `.collection('messages')` such that you access the messages. `data` should now be a QuerySnapshot and you can access the docs in the snapshot with `.docs` (as you already did) and go through all the docs with `.foreach`. A `doc` should than contain the information you want.

```
onPressed: () async {
  var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('chats')
      .doc('i2CTgCsK172ADGN8MFfA')
      .collection('messages')
      .get();
  data.docs.foreach(doc) {
        print(doc['text']);
        print(doc.data()); // this shows all the data that is inside doc
    });
  );
},
```

Comment: yes it worked it shows me Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'
 ty
do u know how to print the docs it self? i mean the string that i have in the masseges

Comment: I changed the answer

Comment: sadly it's not working